# Catch maximum execution time php

Tags: php

i want to create a function that can catch maximum execution time, i have found this function.

```
function runfunction($func,$args,$msgs){
    try {
        $t1 = time();
        $result = "";
        while (true) {
            $time_2 = time();
            $result = call_user_func_array($func, $args);
            if($result){ return $result; }
            $time_spent = time() - $t1;
            $time_funcs = time() - $time_2;
            getThrow($time_spent,$time_funcs,$msgs);
        }
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo "<html>\n<head>\n<title>Time Execution</title>\n</head>\n";
        echo "<body style='font-family: monospace; cursor: default'>\n";
        echo 'Caught exception : ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
        echo "</body>\n</html>";
        exit(1);
    }
}

function getThrow($param1,$param2,$msgs){
    if($param2 >= $this->time_sublimit($param1)) {
        throw new Exception($msgs);
    }
}
```

the concept of function above is to get time length for executed function and then compare it with actual time.

the problem is when the process stuck inside this function for more than 30 second.

```
$result = call_user_func_array($func, $args);
```

i still get this error.

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded
```

is it possible to catch maximum execution time when the process still inside this function.

```
$result = call_user_func_array($func, $args);
```

in this case i am using sqlsrv_connect function.

```
runfunction("sqlsrv_connect", array($this->host, $connectionInfo), $errormessage);
```

i set the maximum execution time for 30 second.

Comment: When the execution time limit is reached, the interpreter will *jump* out of your code and, amongst others, execute the registered [shutdown function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php); you can't get back to the same execution context.

Answer (score 1):

Php Default execution time is 30sec.

You can change by giving below line in top of your script if you need to change execution time for your current script only.

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

30 Second is default time execution limit in PHP, if you wanna increase it, You have to increase the maximum time limit for PHP, like so

```
  ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

300 is for 300 second,
or if you wanna increase it for every script you run by php update it in php.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `xampp\php\php.ini`

Search `max_execution_time`, and changed to

```
max_execution_time=900
```